# Проверка http-ответа сервера из консоли с параметрами

Tags: linux, http, get

Как можно через консоль сделать запрос, чтобы:

1) Обычный запрос - ответ сервера

2) Запрос с параметром "If-Modified-Since" - ответ сервера

Подскажите пожалуйста примером команд.

Comment: Гугл [curl](https://www.google.ru/url?sa=t&source=web&rct=j&url=https://curl.haxx.se/docs/httpscripting.html&ved=2ahUKEwiW1_vw1rDbAhVThqYKHW1DB5YQFjAAegQIBxAB&usg=AOvVaw0nPYOruXzSDcBGpfoP1oiZ) , примеров масса...

Comment: `curl` поможет... если хочешь примеры, то уточняй детально с примерами запросов и в каком виде хочешь получить ответы...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Примерчик запроса на curl с If-Modified-Since:

```
curl -I --header 'If-Modified-Since: Tue, 11 Dec 2012 10:10:24 GMT' http://you.site/
```

Comment: Именно это я искал!

Answer (score 1):

1. программа *curl*:

   - опция `-I` — получить и показать только заголовки
   - опция `-H заголовок` — отправить указанный заголовок

   пример (с заголовком [If-Modified-Since](https://developer.mozilla.org/ru/docs/Web/HTTP/%D0%97%D0%B0%D0%B3%D0%BE%D0%BB%D0%BE%D0%B2%D0%BA%D0%B8/If-Modified-Since)):

   ```
   $ curl -I -H "If-Modified-Since: $(TZ=GMT date +'%a, %d %b %Y %H:%M:%S %Z' -d '1 hour ago')" "https://avatars.mds.yandex.net/get-pdb/877347/0f1a3d3e-7abf-4e02-90f0-7344d1df2411/s1200"
   HTTP/1.1 304 Not Modified
   Server: nginx
   Date: Fri, 01 Jun 2018 07:24:13 GMT
   Content-Length: 0
   Connection: keep-alive
   Keep-Alive: timeout=60
   X-Request-Id: 360160e00dbb438f
   Timing-Allow-Origin: *
   ```
2. программа *wget*:

   - опция `-S` — получить и показать заголовки (чтобы показать только заголовки, надо добавить опцию `-q`)
   - опция `--header=заголовок` — отправить указанный заголовок

   пример:

   ```
   $ wget -S -q --header="If-Modified-Since: $(TZ=GMT date +'%a, %d %b %Y %H:%M:%S %Z' -d '1 hour ago')" "https://avatars.mds.yandex.net/get-pdb/877347/0f1a3d3e-7abf-4e02-90f0-7344d1df2411/s1200"
   ```

---

в примерах для формирования времени использована программа *date*. время берётся «час назад от текущего» (опция `-d '1 hour ago'` — [см. `$ info 'date input formats'`](https://www.gnu.org/software/coreutils/manual/html_node/Date-input-formats.html)).